# Content query web part roll up documents and pages

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-query-web-part

I have created metadata tags for our site content. Site content includes both pages in the pages library and pdfs in document libraries. Content is spread out throughout the site. Is there a way for the cqwp to pull back content from both the document and pages libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, we could not choose two list types at the same time: Documents Library and Pages library:

[image]

We could only choose one list type in one web part.

As a workaround, we could use Content Search Web part, then change the query to meet your requirement:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Julie. I have setup exactly as above and I get no results. If I define a list type I get results.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, and I have changed my reply.

Comment: Appreciate the response Julie. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me as I need to display and group by children terms of a term set. Basically create a link for each parent term and then group by all children on that page.